# MySQL query to save the database name

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Below are the databases and tables I'm working on,

### Database A

---

**tableA**

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ KID║  REVLIMIT    ║ REV  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  13║ 4440         ║  39  ║ 
║  14║ 2340         ║  58  ║ 
║  15║ 852200       ║  69  ║ 
║  16║ 85205        ║  78  ║ 
║  46║ 8500         ║  79  ║ 
║  64║ 853          ║  67  ║ 
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------

### Database B

---

**tableA**

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ KID║  REVLIMIT    ║ REV  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║ 55 ║ 4440         ║  139 ║ 
║ 52 ║ 2340         ║  518 ║ 
║ 122║ 852200       ║  619 ║ 
║ 15 ║ 85205        ║  178 ║ 
║ 251║ 8500         ║  719 ║ 
║ 221║ 853          ║  617 ║ 
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------

I need to search both databases **tableA**  for getting **REV** using **KID** so that I get the below result

**tableC**

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╦═════════════════╗
║ KID║  Model_No    ║ REV  ║  Database_name  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣═════════════════╣
║  13║ 43453453345  ║  39  ║     Database A  ║
║  55║ 2433423423   ║  139 ║     Database B  ║
║  14║ 5566533      ║  58  ║     Database A  ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝═════════════════╝
```

ie the name of the database from where I get the **REV** should also save in **tablec**
I can use only plain MySQL query and I cant change the structure,How to accomplish that in the simplest way?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

union both the tables

```
select kid, rev, 'Database_A' as Database_name from `database_a`.tableA
union
select kid, rev, 'Database_B' as Database_name from `database_b`.tableA;
```